# Build solution using GitHub action

Tags: github, github-actions

I have an Azure Pipeline build step as follows:

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      displayName: dotnet build
      inputs:
        command: build
        workingDirectory: 'Service\XYZ'
        arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration)'
```

I converted this to a GitHub action as follows:

```
    - name: dotnet build
      run: dotnet build --configuration ${{ env.buildConfiguration }}
```

How do I specify workingDirectory in this GitHub action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the directory to the only you want to work in, for example like this:

```
 - name: dotnet build
   run: |
     cd Service\XYZ
     dotnet build --configuration ${{ env.buildConfiguration }}
```